# Flurry Analytics

Tags: xcode, xcode4, cordova, flurry

I've used a previous version of Flurry SDK with xCode 3.2.5 in my mobile application.
Recently, I upgraded to Mac OSX Lion and xCode 4.1. However, I'm finding it hard to integrate the Flurry SDK 3.0.0 with xCode 4.1.
I copied the FlurryAnalytics directory to my project directory, then added it in my xCode project. I changed every occurrence of FlurryAPI with FlurryAnalytics.

The ERROR that I get is:
"*No such file or directory FlurryAnalytics.h"
when I try to add

## import "FlurryAnalytics/FlurryAnalytics.h"

in my Plugins/Flurry.m file or Classes/MyApplicationAppDelegate.m

I'd really appreciate some instructions to add FlurryAnalytics SDK 3.0.0 to my Xcode 4 project.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the solution was simple. 
I just had to add [drag and drop the folder] the Flurry SDK library/folder with the option "Create groups for any added folder". So that the folder gets added as a yellow folder.